# is Javascript window.resizeTo() function considered DOM manipulation?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window):

> The Window interface represents a window containing a DOM document;
>   the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that
>   window. A window for a given document can be obtained using the
>   document.defaultView property.

The specification of the function on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) says:

> CSS Object Model (CSSOM) View Module

What I understood is:

> A Window is an object that it is connected to the document (A window for a given document can be obtained using the
>   document.defaultView property.) The window.resizeTo() function changes the height and the
>   width of the window, hence it changes the attributes of the window of
>   the document, to be specific it changes window.innerWidth and
>   window.innerHeight.

So can I conclude that it is a DOM operation?

Comment: It is safe to assume it's DOM manipulation.

Comment: "can I conclude that it is a DOM operation" — Why does it matter? I can't think of any reason to ask other than (a) to get clarity on something unclear someone else has said (in which case you should ask them what they mean because they know best) or (b) to determine what something that deals with DOM manipulation would do if it came across this (in which case asking what that would do would make more sense)

Comment: It's not DOM manipulation in the strict sense, but it still affects how the document looks. But maybe you could add some context to the question, before this becomes the battle of opinions over some semantic in a very grey area.

Comment: @Quentin I answered to an exam that it is a DOM operation but I have not got the points, I just want to know the true answer

Comment: @Arsen — I could argue it both ways. It largely depends on how you define DOM operation. (This makes it a terrible exam question (at least if it expects a binary answer))